# URL linter not working from cURL

Tags: facebook, curl, graph

I need to update the pages from my website to all have the same og:image. I could use the [Object Debugger website](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), but it would take me hours to do it manually so I built a Bash script to do the job.

Problem is, even when I try manually from the Terminal I'm getting nowhere. It simply won't scrape the updated metas. The og:image (or really any other og:meta-tag) remains the same, like I never entered the cURL command. As a precision, it does work when I try from the Debugger website.

As indicated in the [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/):

```
curl https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json
```

Is there any way I can fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: The cache is automatically updated every 24 hours or so (if someone likes it in that time), why would you risk having your IP blocked for scraping facebook's site just to update the image faster than that?

Comment: Are you correctly encrypting the URL? url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.princesspolymath.com - also try curl -v to get more information about what response you're getting

Comment: Yes but there's old pages, that someone might "Share" (not like). I doubt there's any risk that Facebook would block my IP since they offer everybody to update their og:tags using this method.

Comment: Thanks Kirsten. I've tried to encrypt the Url the way you suggested but this made no difference. -v gave me information about the response, and nothing seems to be negative: it connects my IP to developers.facebook.com and I get a "Done" at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cURL doesn’t follow redirects by default. Use the `-L` option.

Comment: Thanks! This worked just fine. Sorry I don't have enough "level" to upvote.

Comment: That’s quite alright! You can still click the checkmark button next to my answer to mark it as answered, if you like.

Comment: Well, thank you. Apparently you will need the `-L` option even for the new URL.