# Clear Facebook share cache with cURL and lint

Tags: php, facebook, caching, curl, lint

I have the problem with shareing facebook content on my website. It's implemented the 'Like' button but when you 'like' the picture on your facebook profile is shown old picture (obiously cached picture). The things on that website works like this... every day there is a new picture of a girl of the day, but the url is always the same (rewritten by apache).

I must find some way to automatically and periodically (when new picture is set on site) clear facebook cache.

When I put url for which I want to refresh cache directly in the fb debug tool (lint) form and press 'debug' it clears cache and refresh content when somobody likes content on my website.

But the problem is when I try refresh cache automaticaly (through php script or via cron job).
Something like this not working:

```
wget http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.vecernji.hr/djevojka-dana
```

or like this also don't working:

```
curl http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.vecernji.hr/djevojka-dana
```

Also, the php script not working:

```
$url = "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.vecernji.hr/djevojka-dana";
$useragent = "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; en) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.60";

if ( $ch = curl_init( $url ) )
{
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_HEADER , 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , $useragent );

    $str_response = curl_exec( $ch );

    if( curl_errno( $ch ) != 0 )
    {
        $message = 'Girl of the day - cURL exec error: ' . $ch;

        error_log( $message );
    }

    curl_close( $ch );
}
else
{
    $message = 'Girl of the day - cURL init with url: ' . $url . ' failed';

    error_log( $message );
}
```

The content to like is on urls:

http://www.vecernji.hr/djevojka-dana
and
http://www.vecernji.hr/decko-dana

Does anyone know the reason why I can't refresh cache via php script, wget or curl, but when I put given url directly and manually in the lint form and press submit button the the content refreshes?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this because a similar script I had in working condition all of a sudden wasn't doing its job anymore. I figured Facebook prohibited this because a lot of people were using it and causing a heavy load.

Anyway, the next best thing I could do to save time was making a script that outputs ALL the links to the lint tool that need refreshing. Then, I used a tool like Linky to open all the links at once. Bam, all caches cleared.

If you need to do this once a day I guess it could become a bit painful to use this solution but it can be done in 5 seconds while having coffee and also delegated to anyone as its a very simple task. If needed, I am sure you can get a script that automatically opens ur page on that URL at a certain time, selects all and uses Linky. Should be easier than figuring out a way around Facebook's disapproval of CURL for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link to a previous answer of mine below for more information on facebook caching :
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9019926/558021

Comment: I saw that, but that don't work for me because I need to 'attack' Lint tool automatically, with some php script. The problem is when I manually go to the Lint url and put url for which I want clear cache in text box everything went good. Cache is cleared. But when I try to do that with tools like wget or cURL it doesn't work. Cache isn't cleared. I suppose I can use wget or cURL because the form in which we put url to clear cache uses simple GET requests.

Comment: This was taken from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) : `curl https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json`.  That `cURL` code will force your URL to be *scraped*...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

(Credit to Sidnicious: [URL linter not working from cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730682/url-linter-not-working-from-curl))